# Git: force comparison between lines

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am currently using git as a means of tracking some robot source code, that more or less takes the shape of a plaintext file.

Part of the motivation for using Git is that in meetings, I am able to pull up the difference comparison between one commit and another using the powerful Visual Studio Code extension: Git Lens.

This allows the non-tech savvy folks (that I am typically presenting to) to be given a brief oral history of what changes have been made in the code, the motivations behind the change (in the form of the commit message), as well as a graphic on screen detailing the changed characters (the the form of the Gitlens UI)

All has gone pretty well until today. Generally speaking, as the files changed gradually, each time I would be able to pull up the differences in the file and display them on screen, and generally the changes mapped line-for-line.

Today, however the entire file underwent a more transformative change and now the lines that **git** thinks are the same actually aren't. It thinks that there are a bunch of missing/removed lines where there really isn't any, and also thinks that certain lines match up when they don't.

I know the one-to-one relationship on how the files were transformed, I have enough time to do this manually if necessary. I just want to be able to display which lines were changed, possibly forcibly show the git tool how to make sense of these changes. I would like to be able to present these changes to people in meetings and have the actually changed lines line up.

Side motivation: my company so far has been slow to adopt version control. There are however some people who prefer to use version control, but most need to be brought up to speed. The added benefit of my being able to resolve this issue would be me being able to turn around and show someone else in kind.

### Example:

[image: Changes]
[image: Originals]

How to get these two commits to line up properly, even if I have to force it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does plain `git diff` give you?

I'm not familiar with Git Lens, but on command line you can try `git diff --anchor="POSITIONER_BASE      1"`(It's hard to tell from the screenshots how many spaces there are between "BASE" and "1", please adjust based on actual data).  What this does is anchor the rest of the diff from the line starting with that string.

`git diff` has a few other options to specify the diff algorithm. You can play with those as well. E.g. `--minimal` makes it try harder to produce a smaller diff.

Comment: Using the minimal algorithm is what is needed; but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the algorithm in gitlens. I guess I'll add a feature request for that. Using ```git dif --minimal --color-words``` looks like the best currently available option; I don't want to have to scroll through terminal output and describe the changes, but using the ```--color-words``` option puts things __nearly__ side-by-side. Thanks for the suggestion in the ```--minimal``` option!